# uninitialized constant (name error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**actor_drawer.rb**

```
def self.draw(actor)
  pdf = PDF::Writer.new
  actors.each do |actor|
    pdf.text actor.name
  end
      pdf.render
end
```

[screenshot of actor_drawer.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oimTW.png)

```
 class ActorsController < ApplicationController
   require 'actor_drawer'

    def new
        @actor=Actor.new

    end

    def index
        @actors=Actor.all
    @actors = @actors.search(params[:search1] )if (params[:search1] ).present?
       respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      send_data ActorDrawer.draw(@actors), :filename => 'actors.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline'
              end
     end
    end
```

View:

```
<p><%= button_to 'PDF Format', actors_path(:pdf) %></p>
```

**Error:**

```
NameError in ActorsController#index uninitialized constant ActorsController::ActorDrawer......error coming at this code " send_data ActorDrawer.draw(@actors), :filename => 'actors.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline' "
```

Comment: What is full error text?

Comment: NameError in ActorsController#index
uninitialized constant ActorsController::ActorDrawer......error coming at this code "      send_data ActorDrawer.draw(@actors), :filename => 'actors.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline'   "

Comment: And what is inside `actor_drawer.rb`? (assuming you have only one and it's loaded)

Comment: def self.draw(actor)
  pdf = PDF::Writer.new
  actors.each do |actor|
    pdf.text actor.name

  end
      pdf.render
end

Comment: Better edit your question and add it to there

Comment: actor_drawer.rb code  is updated in above image..

Answer (score 0):

Your `actor_drawer.rb` does not contain `ActorDrawer` class/module

```
class ActorDrawer
  def self.draw(actors)
     # all other code
  end
end
```